# How to determine amps for panel

Tags: electrical-panel

May I ask for some assistance to determine how many amps my panel has. I don't see any indication on the panel itself. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your main breaker is 100 amps, so a 100 amp panel.  It might be able to have a bigger breaker if listed for a larger amperage.  The other breakers can add up to more than 100, but you are limited to using less than a 100 amps at a time per side.

Comment: @crip659 answers go in the answers, not in the comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most panels have the largest capacity main breaker installed.  Yours is probably the same, but might be able to have a larger main breaker installed, need someone who knows that panel to be sure.

You have a 100 amp main breaker, so that should be the panels capacity.

The branch breakers can add up to more than the main breaker, but since most of them do not use their full use, this is allowed(within limits).

Panels usually have two sides/connecters so you have 100 amps per side.

Comment: thank you for the informative response. I'm looking to install a EV charger. 14-50 nema possibly. May I ask do you know if this panel can be upgraded to 200 somehow or an entirely new panel needs  to be implemented and everything rewired

Comment: @Master  You have space for more breakers, so a 50 amp breaker might be able to go in.  It will depend on your use of electricity, If using a lot(electric heaters), then might need to upgrade.  Doubt very much if you can go to 200 on that panel, maybe up to 125, but needs to be checked, usually they max out panels.